# Best way to download an external webpage, modify it with js and css, then load it in the view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

**Technologies:** iOS8, SWIFT, XCode 6

Using swift, what is the best way to save an external website's html/css/js, modify that saved data with my own css / js, and then load it in the view. This way, the external page loads with my custom styles/js already implemented.

Comment: Are you actually planning on parsing the CSS and JS files referenced by the html, or are you simply planning on adding your CSS and JS to the existing page?

Comment: Hi Jeremy - just planning on adding the css / js to the existing page. Currently, I have an approach that just loads a webview and then once its finishing loading I execute some js to attach a new stylesheet. The problem, is doing it that way causes a second or two delay on the new styles - so you get a glimpse of the site before it changes. So, I'm looking for a way to make those changes to the website before it fully loads in the view (so the styles are just there immediately). If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how complicated your use of the UIWebView is but, the quickest implementation I can think of (aside from the evaluateJS route you've already done):

Create a property to decide if a request has been hijacked yet (by you).

```
var hijacked = false
```

provide the UIWebViewDelegate protocol method.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    //if true it must be our version, reset hijack and allow to load
    if hijacked {
        hijacked = false
        return true
    }
    //original request.  Don't let it load, instead trigger manual loader.
    else {
        hijacked = true
        manuallyLoadPage(request)
        return false
    }
}
```

Then you just need a method to fetch the page, get the text, manipulate the text, and then load the page with your version.

```
func manuallyLoadPage(request: NSURLRequest) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        var html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        html = html.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</head>", withString: "<script>alert(\"I added this\")</script></head>", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: response.URL!)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is just a quick and dirty approach, you may want to do a more thorough job of tracking which requests are hijacked requests etc...  This one just assumes an even odd kind of approach.  You could obviously manipulate the html however you want, I just added the JS alert as a proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! This seems to work great  and yes I'll definitely look into tracking more thoroughly...

Comment: I don't want to take away from @Jeremy's solution; it does work well for several kinds of problems and is pretty easy to implement. A more general solution, however is to use `NSURLProtocol` to inject yourself into the entire session. Ray Wenderlich does a nice introduction to this in Swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift. I demonstrate a simple caching implementation here: https://github.com/rnapier/RNCachingURLProtocol. (But this is just another option; there's nothing wrong with Jeremy's answer.)

Comment: Yes, NSURLProtocol is an option.  That's why I asked for clarification on his intent.  If he really only cares about stuffing a few lines into the main page, there's no reason to capture all of the other requests.

Comment: @JeremyPope using this approach how would I implement a back and forward button on the UIWebView. So, if a user wants to see their previous web page, they can just click the back button. I've tried this: IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) { webView.goback() } but it doesn't work.